# SQL Server distributed databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

how to link two different database in same SQL Server instance 
and send queries between them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use like below.

```
DB1.dbo.TableFromDB1
DB2.dbo.TableFromDB2
```

DB - database

Answer (score 1):

Look at using synonyms "CREATE SYNONYM".

You can access the databases directly with a full path.  But, that code will break if the database is ever renamed or changed.

Using a synonym, the code can remain unchanged; when the database moves, just update the synonym.

This can be useful when you have a test and production environment.  The code does not have to change just because you move it from test to production and the database names do not have to be identical.